# How to mock a repository using data from xml file?

Tags: testing, mocking, repository, mockito

how to mock a repository with Mockito using data from xml file? I'd  like to keep spring out of it if it's possible.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: Because I don't want a test to be bloated with data it operates on. Moreover, that data is to be shared among several tests.

Comment: Can you make all of your test classes have a common superclass, in which all the mocks are declared, and which has a @Before method that does all the stubbing?

Comment: I suppose I could, but it doesn't seem nice. So there's no simple way to do what I asked for? Mockito doesn't provide such functionality?

Comment: It doesn't have XML parsing built in, no.  You could roll your own with SAX or whatever, but it's certainly not built into Mockito.